# How to count values inside an nested array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an nested array as below:

```
[
  ["States", "Count"],
  ["DISABLE", 13],
  ["DENY", 9],
  ["FAULTY", 11],
  ["OFF", 8],
  ["ON", 20]
];
```

I want to get the count of all the values inside the nested array's 'count' column.

the returning result should be like:61 (13+9+11+8+20)
Is there any way to do this in Javascript/react?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Okay what you have tried and what went wrong. Can you show us your code. Also please click here to read more how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - There is high chance that your question will be down-voted if there is no code or additional info at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to find the sum like below code. Before doing that make sure you removed the first one in your array, because it's a string. I am using `shift()` to remove it. Instead of `shift()` you can use `splice()`.

```js
var a = [
  ["States", "Count"],
  ["DISABLE", 13],
  ["DENY", 9],
  ["FAULTY", 11],
  ["OFF", 8],
  ["ON", 20]
];
a.shift(); // removing first element
var total = a.reduce((sum, item) => sum+=item[1], 0);
console.log(total);
```

Comment: I guess OP doesn't care about mutating the original array, but this will be better if you could compute the total without mutating the array. Something like `a.slice(1).reduce((sum, item) => sum+=item[1], 0);` to first copy all but the first index then reduce over the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the data structure, you probably want to have something like :

```js
{
  'DISABLE': 13,
  'DENY': 9,
  ...
}
```

If you can't, this should work :

```js
const count = array.reduce((acc, cur) => acc += cur[1], 0);
```

Comment: Simpler to just return the new computed sum value `const count = array.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur[1], 0);`

Answer (score 0):

```
const countArr = [
    ["DISABLE", 13],
    ["DENY", 9],
    ["FAULTY", 11],
    ["OFF", 8],
    ["ON", 20]
  ]

  const sum = countArr.reduce((firstParam, secondParam) => {
      const [name, count ] = secondParam
      return firstParam + count
  }, 0) // 61
```

remove your first element in array then try this